# Do we still need the "newtonsoft" tag?

Tags: discussion, retag-request, burninate-request

There are currently 195 questions tagged with [newtonsoft](/questions/tagged/newtonsoft). Per the tag wiki:

> NewtonSoft is a software label by James Newton-King, author of the JSON.NET object serialization library.

However, all of those questions are not asking anything about the software label, *per se*, but rather asking about the *product*: JSON.Net.

Do we still need the [newtonsoft](/questions/tagged/newtonsoft) tag, or can we merge all of existing questions tagged "newtonsoft" into the tag [json.net](/questions/tagged/json.net)?

Comment: I'll abstain since I'm biased.

Comment: @DaveNewton Okay.

Comment: Right, here are all the results of all questions in the tag that are not tagged 'json' or 'json.net'. Not sure how/if it helps the point, but here it is! http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/111341/proof-that-all-newtonsoft-questions-are-about-json-net

Comment: Burn it down, i have already suggested this as a synonym. but there are only two votes until now. Go and support it. http://stackoverflow.com/tags/json.net/synonyms

Answer (score 5):

I **support** the burnination.

For one, I've ruled out a lot of the questions with this: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/111341/all-newtonsoft-questions-with-no-obvious-link-to-json-net

Now, for the rest: (excuse the length, SO has no folding tag)

[How to access elements of a JArray (or iterate over them)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16045569/how-to-access-elements-of-a-jarray): JArray = Json.NET.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14096010/dynamic-objects-in-winphone8: The dynamic objects are Json.NET.

[Silverlight File Not Found System.Runtime.Serialization on Deserialization from Newtonsoft](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10238187/silverlight-file-not-found-system-runtime-serialization-on-deserialization-from): JsonConvert => Json.NET

[TypeNameHandling in Newtonsoft requires $type to be the first property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15570510/typenamehanling-in-newtonsoft-requires-type-to-be-the-first-property): Doesn't SEEM like Json at a glance, but answers metion it so I assume it is.

[Parse and filter javascript array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2324422/parse-and-filter-javascript-array): Completely JSON.Net.

[Custom impromptuobject for json.net deserialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15873136/custom-impromptuobject-for-json-net-deserialization): JObject = Json.NET.

[twitter API with MonoDevelop and C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8342567/twitter-api-with-monodevelop-and-c-sharp): Newtonsoft.Json => Json.NET

[Separate projects in the same solution. "The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11506768/separate-projects-in-the-same-solution-the-located-assemblys-manifest-definit): RavenDB uses Json.NET.

[How to correctly model loosely-typed properties in RavenDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9088708/how-to-correctly-model-loosely-typed-properties-in-ravendb): RavenDB uses Json.NET.

[missing a using directive or an assembly reference issue after deploying an ASP.NET "Website"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12091141/missing-a-using-directive-or-an-assembly-reference-issue-after-deploying-an-asp): using statement question including Json.NET.

[Why is selenium producing this error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6774619/why-is-selenium-producing-this-error): FileLoadException details indicate a Json.NET requirement.

[how to get newtonsoft to deserialize yes and no to boolean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14524669/how-to-get-newtonsoft-to-deserialize-yes-and-no-to-boolean): Obvious JSON.

[Use different versions of dll file in one app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15703991/use-different-versions-of-dll-file-in-one-app): Problems with two different libraries depending on Json.NET.

[Add additional References when compliling code at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12488782/add-additional-references-when-compliling-code-at-runtime): Uses LINQ to JSON.

[Return some fields from ASP.NET Web API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12662259/return-some-fields-from-asp-net-web-api): JSON response.

[Error when updating Twitter status with Twitterizer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5552278/error-when-updating-twitter-status-with-twitterizer): Json.NET error.

[Newtonsoft ignore attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6309725/newtonsoft-ignore-attributes): Json.NET.

And lastly, if it is accepted, questions to retag (I'm not sure if retagging is done automatically on burnination): https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/111402/all-questions-in-newtonsoft